# Useless call std::move with std::vector::at

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I'm examining the course from Packt Publishing about C++17 features.
In the first lecture on the STL-containers I've met the next piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
void quick_remove_at(std::vector<T> &v, std::size_t idx)
{
    if (idx < v.size()) {
        v.at(idx) = std::move(v.back());
        v.pop_back();
    }
}
```

I can't get why `std::move` is used. Value on the right side is copied anyway. Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it is *copied anyway*?

Comment: But what if you want to save on some of that copying logic? Say for example `T` is another `vector`. You can copy the contents of the last `vector` or, since you're going to pop it anyway, reassign a couple pointers from the `vector` that's about to die to the destination and save on copying all of the elements.

Comment: One of the (possible)  properties of a vector is that it is ordered - this seems to change the ordering.

Comment: Looks odd to me to use `v.at(idx)` rather than `v[idx]`, given you've just done the bounds check...

Comment: @mistertribs It is also odd to simply ignore on failure.

Comment: Sorry, I was drunk. I've got how it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very next statement removes the last element of the vector. `std::vector::at` returns a reference, and the assignment operator then executes, well, an assignment operation.

If `T` implements move semantics, this will result in the last value in the vector being move-assigned into position #*idx*. If `T` implements a move-assignment operator, this will make use of it. No copy will be made, this will leave the last element of the vector in some valid, but unspecified state, and then it gets immediately popped from the vector, and gone for good.

If `T` does not implement move semantics, this will devolve into a normal copy/assignment.

Comment: If you are implementing your own class, it is your responsibility to correctly implement move semantics, and leave the class instance in some valid, but unspecified state, after it is moved from, so that (amongst other things) its destructor properly disposes of it. I discovered that, myself, some time ago.

Comment: @t.niese "Isn't the in some valid, but unspecified state only guaranteed for objects of the std library?" - No. That is something that you yourself must also ensure, if your class can be moved from.